# android:background image doesn't show up on the first time when coming from invisible to visible

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a relativelayout inside a relativelayout  and it's all inside an include. 
The outer relativelayout has an android:background which is an image.
The inner has other image, but in the same way.
**It's all invisible.**
there's a button that's responsible for toggling the visibility.

When it becomes visible - the inner image is shown but the outer doesn't.
BUT if I click to hide and then click again to show - the outer image shows too.

Here is the relevant xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/display_prefs_dialog_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible" >

    <include
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        layout="@layout/display_prefs_dialog" >
    </include>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And inside the include:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/display_prefs_dialog"
    android:layout_width="327dp"
    android:layout_height="218dp"
    android:background="@drawable/display_win" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/display_letters_bg"
        android:layout_width="262dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:background="@drawable/display_letter_frame" >
```

JAVA code:

```
final ImageButton btnDisplay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);         
        final RelativeLayout prefsInnerDialog = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.display_prefs_dialog);       
        final RelativeLayout prefsDialog = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.display_prefs_dialog_layout);


btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {                               
                int visibility = prefsDialog.getVisibility();
                if (visibility == View.VISIBLE) 
                {
                    prefsDialog.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    prefsDialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: can you paste your java code...

Comment: post your button OnClick code as well

Comment: Ain't you toggling the visibility of prefsInnerDialog ?

Comment: @TarunMaheshwari no, prefsDialog is the most outer layout. and that's the part that gets invisible and visible. + It's working, but not on the first time.

Comment: Look at your xml your relative layouts are visible. First time when you would click on the button `int visibility = prefsDialog.getVisibility();` will return VISIBLE and your view will be made invisible.

Comment: @TarunMaheshwari I've reorganized the code in the question.
As you can see:
prefsDialog =display_prefs_dialog_layout. 
and there:     android:visibility="invisible"

Comment: Check out the views in hierarchyviewer and their visibility.

Comment: where is the button in your xml file.

Comment: @ Agarwal Why does it matter? As I said - it's not like it's not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have been in the same kind of the requirement today as yours and have done something similar to this, and its working for me.
Posting the same sample code for you, that might help you..!

**Java File : Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    RelativeLayout prefsInnerDialog, prefsDialog;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        prefsInnerDialog = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.display_prefs_dialog);
        prefsDialog = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.display_prefs_dialog_layout);
    }
    public void toggleIt(View v) {
        int visibility = prefsDialog.getVisibility();
        if (visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
            prefsDialog.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            prefsDialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

**First XML : main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="toggleIt"></Button>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/display_prefs_dialog_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible">
        <include android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" layout="@layout/mainsecond">
        </include>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Second XML : mainsecond.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/display_prefs_dialog" android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="480dp" android:background="@drawable/mainbg">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/display_letters_bg"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="250dp" android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/databg">
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Looking at your code , i feel like there is nothing wrong in the java code, you having problem just because the *bad* RelativeLayout usages.

Comment: Just saw your answer. Thanks, I'll look on it tommorow and let you know.

Comment: in fact I didn't have time to try and use it yet, But I saw that if I won't approve your answer soon- you'd get only half the bounty points... So I approve it for now, and I believe this is probably the solution. thanks

Comment: Please you dont need to do this to award bounty, anyways thanks,,yes i have used the above code in my app so i am sure its working..also you can click on +50, [more to read about bounty here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)